# How to get "picturebox.Handle.ToInt32" value in Windows to image control Value in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have windows form  code and I want to use it in Asp.Net. In this program,I use image control instead of pixture box so I dont access to handle method and I dont know, What is the equivalent of picturebox.handle value in Windows to image control.properties Value in ASP.net C#.
Pic_Film is my picturebox.initCam is a method in myCam class. What should i write instead of "Pic_Film.Handle.ToInt32" ?

```
  myCam.initCam(Pic_Film.Handle.ToInt32)
```

I tested following code but I had a error :Unable to cast object of type 'system.web.UI.WebControls.Image'to type 'System.IConvertible'

```
 myCam.initCam(Convert.ToInt32(Page.FindControl("Pic_Film")));
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to hook up a webcam in an ASP.NET page.  You can not.  This is not the correct technology to do that.

Comment: Yes,what is the correct technology to do this?